# Scipy sparse matrix from edge list

Tags: python, r, matrix, scipy, sna

How to convert an ***edge list*** ([data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdpiK.png)) to a python ***scipy sparse matrix*** to get this result:

[image: sparse matrix in R]

Dataset (where 'agn' is node category one and 'fct' is node category two):

```
data['agn'].tolist()
['p1', 'p1', 'p1', 'p1', 'p1', 'p2', 'p2', 'p2', 'p2', 'p3', 'p3', 'p3', 'p4', 'p4', 'p5']

data['fct'].tolist()
['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5', 'f6', 'f5', 'f6', 'f7', 'f7', 'f8', 'f9']
```

(not working) python code:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, coo_matrix

csr_matrix((data_sub['agn'].values, data['fct'].values), 
                    shape=(len(set(data['agn'].values)), len(set(data_sub['fct'].values))))
```

-> **Error**: "TypeError: invalid input format"
Do I really need three arrays to construct the matrix, like the examples in the scipy csr documentation do suggest (can only use two links, sorry!)?

(working) R code used to construct the matrix with only two vectors:

```
library(Matrix)

grph_tim <- sparseMatrix(i = as.numeric(data$agn), 
                     j = as.numeric(data$fct),  
                     dims = c(length(levels(data$agn)),
                              length(levels(data$fct))),
                     dimnames = list(levels(data$agn),
                                     levels(data$fct)))
```

---

**EDIT**:
It finally worked after I modified the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688062/converting-a-1-2gb-list-of-edges-into-a-sparse-matrix) and added the needed array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as ss

def read_data_file_as_coo_matrix(filename='edges.txt'):
    "Read data file and return sparse matrix in coordinate format."

    # if the nodes are integers, use 'dtype = np.uint32'
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = '\t', encoding = 'utf-8')

    # where 'rows' is node category one and 'cols' node category 2
    rows = data['agn']  # Not a copy, just a reference.
    cols = data['fct']

    # crucial third array in python, which can be left out in r
    ones = np.ones(len(rows), np.uint32)
    matrix = ss.coo_matrix((ones, (rows, cols)))
    return matrix
```

Additionally, I converted the string names of the nodes to integers. Thus `data['agn']` becomes `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]` and `data['fct']` becomes `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]`.

I get this sparse matrix:

> (0, 0)  1
>     (0, 1)    1
>     (0, 2)    1
>     (0, 3)    1
>     (0, 4)    1
>     (1, 2)    1
>     (1, 3)    1
>     (1, 4)    1
>     (1, 5)    1
>     (2, 4)    1
>     (2, 5)    1
>     (2, 6)    1
>     (3, 6)    1
>     (3, 7)    1
>     (4, 8)    1

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want : what are the coefficients and what are the indices ? From the picture of the data (you shouldn't put a picture btw, just copy paste the data as text so that we can use it) we see indices that are p1,f1 etc these are not integers (as far as I can tell) so they can't be used directly as indices.

Comment: Even if I use numeric values instead, I still get the same error!
data_a = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]
data_b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]. 


mtx = csr_matrix((data_a, data_b), 
                        shape=(len(set(data_a)), len(set(data_b))))

Comment: Yes, the `scipy` sparse needs the `data` as well as the `rows` and `cols` arrays.  It does not assume that the `data` values are all `1`.  The original sparse matrix code was used for linear algebra problems, where the `data` is floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It finally worked after I modified the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688062/converting-a-1-2gb-list-of-edges-into-a-sparse-matrix) and added the needed array:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as ss

def read_data_file_as_coo_matrix(filename='edges.txt'):
    "Read data file and return sparse matrix in coordinate format."

    # if the nodes are integers, use 'dtype = np.uint32'
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, sep = '\t', encoding = 'utf-8')

    # where 'rows' is node category one and 'cols' node category 2
    rows = data['agn']  # Not a copy, just a reference.
    cols = data['fct']

    # crucial third array in python, which can be left out in r
    ones = np.ones(len(rows), np.uint32)
    matrix = ss.coo_matrix((ones, (rows, cols)))
    return matrix
```

Additionally, I converted the string names of the nodes to integers. Thus `data['agn']` becomes `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]` and `data['fct']` becomes `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8]`.

I get this sparse matrix:

> (0, 0)  1
>     (0, 1)    1
>     (0, 2)    1
>     (0, 3)    1
>     (0, 4)    1
>     (1, 2)    1
>     (1, 3)    1
>     (1, 4)    1
>     (1, 5)    1
>     (2, 4)    1
>     (2, 5)    1
>     (2, 6)    1
>     (3, 6)    1
>     (3, 7)    1
>     (4, 8)    1